# Is it possible to use GitJournal on a Mac?

Tags: git, journaling

I got interested in [GitJournal](https://github.com/GitJournal/GitJournal), but as far as I can see there are only mobile applications.

Is it possible to use it on a Mac (possibly from the command-line) and, if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

So far it isn't. I'm still working on [Desktop App](https://github.com/GitJournal/GitJournal/issues/137) support. Please vote on the issue, and I can accordingly prioritize it.

Also there is a SubReddit - https://reddit.com/r/GitJournal - maybe that would be a better place for questions about GitJournal.